# What is meant by $X\setminus V(s)$, for $s$ a global section?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

I'm having trouble understanding the definition of an ample line bundle as given in my lecture notes:

> **Definition:** Let $X$ be a quasi-compact scheme, a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$ is called *ample* if for every $x\in X$ there exists $m\ge 1$ and $s\in \mathcal{L}^{\otimes m}(X)$ a global section such that $D(s):= X\setminus V(s)$ is affine and $x\in D(s)$.

---

What is meant by $X\setminus V(s)$, for $s$ a global section? My first guess was that maybe this is defined via a cover of $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ with $U_i=\operatorname{Spec} A_i$ open affine in such a way that $s$ locally (i.e. on $U_i$) becomes an element of $A_i$. (Does this work?$^1$) This would give us $U_i\setminus V(s)$ in a canonical way and $X\setminus V(s)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\left(U_i\setminus V(s)\right)$ would make sense.
However, I'm not sure if this is the correct way of looking at this.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

$^1$ The problem here might be that $s$ is a global section and thus not defined on $U_i$ but we could restrict it to each of the $U_i$.

Comment: A global section has a vanishing locus, which is a closed subscheme of the ambiemt scheme $X$. You are right that you can think about this in terms of pulling back your global section to an affine open cover. And if $U_i$ is an open of $X$ then there is a restriction map of global sections, so $s$ is defined on the $U_i$.

Comment: @user45878 Thanks for the comment/answer. Do you know if we can also regain $s$ via gluing of the structure sheaves of the $U_i$'s?